# local linux user with pam ssh and tacacs

Tags: client

I would like to configure on a linux client ssh to use TACACS+ server.
To do so I configure sshd on pam.d directory to auth using pam_tacplus.so.

#### The problem

Unless I have the user LOCALLY declared on the linux machine - I can't authenticate it.
This is quite normal as I must have a user on a linux session.

#### The question(s)

Do I HAVE TO declare the user locally when the 'device' is a linux machine? (I know that on network devices I don't).
If I don't have to, then how do I grab the user's permissions, environment, etc from the tacacs server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TACACS+ doesn't natively provide sufficient details to fulfill the "name service" needs of Linux systems. It is this functionality of glibc that is responsible for providing the system with details for the user's 'passwd' entry, for example.

It is would be possible to achieve this with a custom NSS module, which could pull the correct details from the TACACS+ backend. This would be similar to what is done for LDAP-based authentication, where a user is given additional attribute that represent items like UID, GID, HOME, SHELL, etc.

I am not aware if there is an open source module that provides this functionality today, but it possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did solve it with custom NSS. It works fine.

Comment: could you give some detail about the customization that you made, I am having similar problem. Thanks

Comment: @chandank You'll likely need to write a custom NSS module. You can find documentation about the API for this here: https://goo.gl/lvwVHn

There is a sketch of how this might work in the document: https://goo.gl/tWeFqx

If I was to work on this myself, I might skip the reverse lookup pieces (uid###) entries, and just rely on NSCD to provide caching.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for response. writing custom NSS module looks a good solution. However, for meanwhile I did a short cut method, I modified the pam_tacplus module and it is working now.